How to use a list in json file as an argument for case in javascript
so there is my chrome extension code (not fully but other part is just html and css code):
switch (window.location.hostname) {
    case "www.youtube.com":
        document.head.innerHTML = generateSTYLES();
        document.body.innerHTML = generateHTML("YouTube");
    break
}

So i want to put other website than YouTube, but i don't to just copy this code as many time as i need to add website. I want to put all the website in a json file and then execute this code for every of them. Can anyone help with doing it in javascript and the json file ? Thanks

Where do you get your JSON from? How does that JSON look like? Do you want to execute the same code for all elements in this JSON or do the calls and/or parameters change for every site ?

So for the json, i did'nt already create one bc i don't know much but i wan't just a simple list of urls, the json will be located in the same directory that the JS file, and i want to do the same action for everysite

It's a bad idea because fetching a file can take a lot of time as the request will be enqueued after the website's other resources. Although you can use a synchronous XMLHttpRequest, but it's deprecated and it generates a warning in console. P.S. Your code breaks all modern sites because changing innerHTML unregisters event listeners added from JS.

You can try this:
json file:
{
  "websites": [
    {
      "hostname": "www.youtube.com",
      "styles": "generateSTYLES()",
      "html": "generateHTML('YouTube')"
    },
    {
      "hostname": "www.google.com",
      "styles": "generateGoogleStyles()",
      "html": "generateExampleHTML('Google')"
    }
    // so on
  ]
}

JS code:
try {
  const response = await fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL('websites.json'));
  const data = await response.json();

  const currentHostname = window.location.hostname;

  data.websites.forEach(site => {
    if (site.hostname === currentHostname) {
      document.head.innerHTML = eval(site.styles);
      document.body.innerHTML = eval(site.html);
    }
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error fetching or applying customizations:', error);
}


It didn't worked

Where did this fail? please share details

i didn't actually know but when i go to youtube the page doesn't change and it load Youtube, when i remove your part of code it work. I created the json name with websites.json as name as it is writted on your post
